# Problem Specifying Jetpack Room Schema Location

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm in the process of converting my android app from using simple file IO to using a proper database, so I've been going through the tutorials for Android Jetpack's Room. I'm having problems  trying to specify the room.schemaLocation argument. My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.austinweaver.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 13
        versionName "2.4.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
*       javaCompileOptions {
*           annotationProcessorOptions {
*               arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
*           }
*       }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.0"
}
```

The block marked with the *s is the issue: without it, my app runs fine but tells me to specify the room.schemaLocation. With that block, the gradle sync works but then the app build fails with the following message:

```
Unable to find method 'java.nio.file.Path.of(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;'
java.nio.file.Path.of(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/file/Path;

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I've tried restarting Android Studio and tried some scattered solutions I found by trying to google the error message, but all the relevant things I found were deprecated or didn't work.

Let me know if there's any information I should have included here, because I'm not sure what else in my project even relates to this. Thanks for any help!

Edit: my project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: What version of room and android gradle plugin do you have

Comment: @Rafsanjani from that build.gradle file, Room version 2.4.0, unless you're asking about something else. Where would I find the android gradle plugin version?